# Validate ~/.XCompose

Tags: input-method, compose-key

I'm working on creating my own compose key sequences in `~/.XCompose`. As I add more and more sequences, occasionally I make typos or use the same sequence for different symbols.

### Examples:

**Typo / Non-Existent Codes**

```
<Multi_key> <non-existent-keysym> : other-non-existent-keysym
```

**Full Collision**

```
<Multi_key> <a> <b> : x      # overrule by 2nd rule
<Multi_key> <a> <b> : y
```

**Prefix Collisions**

```
<Multi_key> <a> <b> <c> : y 
<Multi_key> <a> <b> : x      # overruled by 1st rule
```

### Question

Is there a command that validates my `~/.XCompose` file. Minimum requirement is a binary answer: Either »*your XCompose is error free*« or »*your XCompose contains errors*«. In case there are errors, a helpful error message like »*collision for rule sequence prefix*   « would be welcome.

### What I Tried

I created `~/.XCompose` containing all errors from above and opened a text editor. The text editor shows no errors (on the console). Correct and non-overruled sequences work, all other sequences are ignored.

I read `man 5 XCompose`. In the documentation itself I found nothing helpful. I looked at the references at the end of `man 5 XCompose`. Only `mkcomposecache(1)` looks promising (judging from the [googled manpage](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man8/mkcomposecache.8.html)), but seems to be missing on my system (Linux Mint 18.3). Neither `man -k mkcomposecache` nor `apt search mkcomposecache` find anything.

**Edit:** As @quixotic suggested, I compiled `mkcomposecache` from [the sources](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/mkcomposecache/) and ran it, but its exits status is `1`, no matter what compose file I choose (with or without errors). There is no error message. No cache is generated. Example of how I call the program:

```
$ mkcomposecache en_US.UTF-8 /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose /tmp/
* XOpenDisplay: Success
$ echo $?
1
```

The file `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` is Ubuntu's original compose file and should be error free. I guess there is a reason why it is not packaged in the Ubuntu and Arch Linux repositories.

I doubt that `mkcomposecache` is what I need, even if it would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reverse engineered [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/composekey/iijdllfdmhbmlmnbcohgbfagfibpbgba?hl=en-US) and made it into a little web app.

You can use it here: https://jsfiddle.net/9p1s60of/

Here's an image of the tool in action:

[image: the tool in action]

Answer (score 3):

A bit crude, but you could just quickly hack something together using associative arrays, with e.g. `awk`:

For an input file like

```
<Multi_key> <a> <t> : y
<Multi_key> <a> <g> : y
<Multi_key> <a> <b> : x
<Multi_key> <a> <b> : y
<Multi_key> <a> <x> <c> : y 
<Multi_key> <a> <x> : x
<Multi_key> <a> <g> : Q
<Multi_key> <a> <n> : y
```

this command

```
awk '!d[$2][$3]{d[$2][$3]=1;next} {print $0 " PROBLEM!"}' myFile
```

will output

```
<Multi_key> <a> <b> : y PROBLEM!
<Multi_key> <a> <x> : x PROBLEM!
<Multi_key> <a> <g> : Q PROBLEM!
```

To also see the  line it conflicts with:

```
awk 'c=d[$2][$3]{print $0 " COLLISION: " c;next} {d[$2][$3]=$0}' myFile
```

Result:

```
<Multi_key> <a> <b> : y COLLISION: <Multi_key> <a> <b> : x
<Multi_key> <a> <x> : x COLLISION: <Multi_key> <a> <x> <c> : y
<Multi_key> <a> <g> : Q COLLISION: <Multi_key> <a> <g> : y
```