# Long xcompose combinations don't work in some programs

Tags: compose-key

I have the following lines in `~/.XCompose`:

```
<Multi_key> <n> <a> <b> <l> <a> : "∇"
<Multi_key> <i> <n> <t> <e> <g> <r> : "∫"
```

The first line has 5 keys after `<Multi_key>`, hence it works in firefox, emacs, and konsole. The second line has 6 keys after `<Multi_key>`, and it seems that's one too long. In emacs it works, in firefox it doesn't work at all, in konsole I get ∫ symbol after the fifth key `<g>` and I don't need to type `<r>`.

Of course I actually have more lines in `~/.XCompose`, but they are all similar to these two. And it seems that *5 keys* is some kind of limit. How do I make it so that all these lines work in all programs?

---

I am using Debian 10 (Buster), KDE, firefox 68.2.0esr. If I run `im-config`, it prints the following:

```
Current configuration for the input method:
 * Active configuration: missing (normally missing)
 * Normal automatic choice: none (normally ibus or fcitx or uim)
 * Override rule: zh_CN,fcitx:zh_TW,fcitx:zh_HK,fcitx:zh_SG,fcitx
 * Current override choice:  (en_US)
 * Current automatic choice: none
 * Number of valid choices: 1 (normally 1)
The override rule is defined in /etc/default/im-config.
The configuration set by im-config is activated by re-starting X.
Explicit selection is not required to enable the automatic configuration if the active one is default/auto/cjkv/missing.
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to an incompletely formatted XCompose file.

Using [this validator](https://jsfiddle.net/9p1s60of/) ( tip: "[Validate ~/.XCompose](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/415202/37153)"), perhaps you you need to change it to:

```
<Multi_key> <n> <a> <b> <l> <a> : "∇" U2207 #NABLA
<Multi_key> <i> <n> <t> <e> <g> <r> : "∫" U222B #INTEGRAL
```